# Do jQuery and ExtJS play nicely together?

Tags: jquery, extjs

I am responsible for maintaining and updating  an AJAX web app written in Zend Framework and jQUERY.  The app presents certain information in a grid format. The original dev team chose to use jqGrid for this. I have tried to modify the jqGrid code and found it very difficult. I searched for documentation and didn't find any. I even tried to contact the component's author, and received no reply.

I have given up on trying to work with jqGrid I want to re-write the primary grid interface in ExtJS. But our front-end is written entirely in jQuery. I don't know enough about ExtJS to know whether it can seamlessly function in parallel with jQuery. I don't want to have to perform major front-end code re-writes throughout the app to make this work.

Please let me know if this is feasible. Thanks.

Comment: I've used both in a project and they seems to be playing nice together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from using Ext with jQuery. They won't really "work together", but there's no problem having them on the same page.

The Ext class system is self contained, doesn't modify the prototypes at all and all the css is scoped to Ext components.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. I will attempt to persuade my employer to let me move ahead with Ext.